Im trying to add a progress bar in kivy md, but I can't figure out how to deal with an error
I started playing around with kivy to try to add visuals to a side project, so far I'm mostly just trying to get the hang of the different functions and how things work. Everything was working as expected until I tried adding kivyMD code and now I keep getting this error.
ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions
My python file looks like this:
import random
import pickle
import pygame
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
kv = Builder.load_file("marina.kv")

global starting
starting = 1

global health
health = 10
global damage
damage = 5
global string
string = "i slap your face"

def punch():
    print('i slap your face')
    global health
    health= health - damage
    print(health)       


class clicky(Screen):
        def press_it(self):
    # Grab the current progress bar value
            current = starting
        # If statement to start over after 100
            if current == 1:
                current = 0
        # Increment value by .25
                while current <= 1:
                    current += .25
        # Update the progress bar
        # Update the label
                #self.my_label.text = f'{int(current*100)}% Progress'
                    print(current)
#        def build(self):
#            return kv
class arena(Screen):
    def hi(self):
        print("hi")
    def samplePunch(self):
        punch()
#        print('i slap your face')
#        healthr = health - damage
#        health = health - damage
#        print(healthr)
        self.button = Label(text=string)
        self.ids.display.add_widget(self.button)
    def press(self):
        clicky().press_it()
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [arena(name="b"), clicky(name="bt")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)
sm.current = "bt"

class marinaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_all_kv_files("screens")
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    marinaApp().run()

And my .kv file looks like this:
<arena>:
    name: "b"
    FloatLayout:
        id: layout
        Image:
            source:'grass.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.8
            pos_hint:{"top":1}
        Image:
            source:'dummiTwo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.15
            pos_hint:{"top":0.88, "x":0.08}
        Image:
            source:'dummi.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.15
            pos_hint:{"top":0.5, "x":-0.1}
        FloatLayout:
            id: display
            Button:
                text:"scratch"
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint:{"top":0.1, "x":0.0}
                on_press: root.samplePunch()
            Button:
                text:"stare"
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"top":0.1, "x":0.50}
                on_press: root.press()
            MDProgressBar:
                value: 50  # Set the current health value (adjust as needed)
                min: 1
                max: 100
<clicky>:
    name: "bt"
    Widget:
        Label:
            id:my_label
            text: "0% Progress"


        Button:
            text: "Press Me!"
            on_press: root.press_it()
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "b"

So at first I tried using self.load_all_kv_files("screens") and throwing it into a few different places. Then I looked up some tutorials and documents and tried restructuring the code outright.
Heres the restructure attempt
import kivy
import random
import pickle
import pygame
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp




Builder.load_string("""
<arena>:
    name: "b"
    FloatLayout:
        id: layout
        Image:
            source:'grass.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.8
            pos_hint:{"top":1}
        Image:
            source:'dummiTwo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.15
            pos_hint:{"top":0.88, "x":0.08}
        Image:
            source:'dummi.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint_y:0.15
            pos_hint:{"top":0.5, "x":-0.1}
        FloatLayout:
            id: display
            Button:
                text:"scratch"
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint:{"top":0.1, "x":0.0}
                on_press: root.samplePunch()
            Button:
                text:"stare"
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"top":0.1, "x":0.50}
                on_press: root.press()
            MDProgressBar:
                value: 50  # Set the current health value (adjust as needed)
                min: 1
                max: 100
<clicky>:
    name: "bt"
    Widget:
        Label:
            id:my_label
            text: "0% Progress"


        Button:
            text: "Press Me!"
            on_press: root.press_it()
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "b"
""")

global starting
starting = 1

global health
health = 10
global damage
damage = 5
global string
string = "i slap your face"

def punch():
    print('i slap your face')
    global health
    health= health - damage
    print(health)       


class clicky(Screen):
        def press_it(self):
    # Grab the current progress bar value
            current = starting
        # If statement to start over after 100
            if current == 1:
                current = 0
        # Increment value by .25
                while current <= 1:
                    current += .25
        # Update the progress bar
        # Update the label
                #self.my_label.text = f'{int(current*100)}% Progress'
                    print(current)
#        def build(self):
#            return kv
class arena(Screen):
    def hi(self):
        print("hi")
    def samplePunch(self):
        punch()
#        print('i slap your face')
#        healthr = health - damage
#        health = health - damage
#        print(healthr)
        self.button = Label(text=string)
        self.ids.display.add_widget(self.button)
    def press(self):
        clicky().press_it()

screen_manager = ScreenManager()
  
# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(arena(name ="arena"))
screen_manager.add_widget(clicky(name ="clicky"))

class marinaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    marinaApp().run()

*Ideally I would like to keep things formated in the old way, or I guess I should say using a seperate .kv file, but I'm really not sure what im missing with this error and how to change the order things initialize in.

Maybe you need to use MDApp instead of App in your marinaApp.
